# Accessing Push Notification on Windows Phone 8 from C++

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am working on an application for Windows Phone 8, and checking the push notification interface. I have found in the documentation the different steps to do it, but I have only found that on the .NET documentation how to create a notification channel and obtain the URL to push the notifications  (here [1]), but I can't seem to find it how to access from a C++ application (I am checking here, on Windows Phone Runtime API [2])

Is there any way of creating a notification channel (to be able to send notifications to the app) from a C++ application. If not, the only solution is to create a .NET application? Or there is any way of circumvent this?

Thanks

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.notification(v=vs.105).aspx
[2] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207212(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, the answer right now (May 2013) is NO. Only C# applications can use these features.